# React Apollo and conditional Boolean variables

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I have this Apollo Query and the GraphQL query below... And it works, but unfortunately not as I desire ...

Now I get "WHERE": casinos has popular=true/false AND mobile=true/false AND awarded=true/false and so on ... (with emphasisis on "AND")

popular, mobile, awarded and live are checkboxes on a webpage which I use to filter results which updates when the user check/uncheck them.

**What I want**

When a user checks for example popular and awarded, I want to show all the casinos which have awarded set to true, and all casinos which has popular set to true. NOT casinos which has popular AND rewarded set to true.

How?

**React/JS:**

```
 <Query query={CASINO_QUERY} 
                     variables={{ 
                                popular: this.state.popular,
                                awarded: this.state.awarded,
                                mobile: this.state.mobile,
                                live: this.state.live
                                 }}>
                {({ data, loading, error }) => {
                  if (loading) return <p>Loading…</p>;
                  if (error) return <p>Something went wrong</p>;
                  return (
                    <div>
                      {data.casinos.map((casino) => (
                        <Featured key={casino.id} casino={casino} />
                      ))}
                    </div>
                  );
                }}
              </Query>
```

**GraphQL query:**

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

const CASINO_QUERY = gql`
query casinos($popular: Boolean, $awarded: Boolean, $mobile: Boolean, $live: Boolean ) {
    casinos(where: { 
        Popular: $popular
        Awarded: $awarded
        Mobile: $mobile
        Live: $live
        
    }) 
    {
    slug
    name
    logo {
      url
    }
    rating
    owner
    founded
    payout_percentage
    expert_consensus
    }
  }
}
`;

export default CASINO_QUERY;
```

Comment: not a query[-ing] problem ... all depends on API implementation ... it looks like this API doesn't support any logical constructions/syntax ... as a workaround you can use alieses, one for popular, 2nd for awarded

Comment: Thank you for your answer xadm... I will try it today and get back, I hope its what I am looking for. Do you know any example of how its normally accomplished without the work around?

Comment: build API with more advanced where logic - trees (object) with 'and', 'or' props (arrays of args)